# Detecting wscript.exe Path

Tags: windows

Where is wscript.exe located in Windows? Is is possible to locate the path by the help of Windows Registry?

I need this for my application and it would be great to have a common solution that would give correct location for ranging between XP to Windows 10.

Comment: If you need to know then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: May I ask the reason? There are lots of variable in this case. OS infrastructure and custom Windows install may change the wscript.exe location. Would you mind reseting your down vote please?

Comment: The native version is always in `system32`, this path can be retrieved with `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` (`SHGetFolderPath()` on XP) but there really is no point as its already in the Windows search path so can be called without needing a path. If the OS is 64bit there will be a 32bit version in `SysWow64`, `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` can give you this path as well.

Comment: Thanks @AlexK. May there be any possibility if the wscript entry can be deleted from Windows PATH?

Comment: Its the path to system32 thats in %PATH%, if its missing a user would have to have deliberately removed it.

Comment: Thanks @AlexK. I see. I need to retrieve %PATH% and append filename properly. But is there any short-cut for wscript.exe like %COMSPEC%?

Comment: Nope.  Its still unclear why you need this, why not just use `wscript.exe` on its own.

Comment: No just want to keep the code simpler. If there were a short-cut like COMSPEC, I would not need to construct wscript.exe path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the system32 directory (+syswow64 for the 32bit exe)

You can verify this at the command line with `where wscript`.

Since its in the `PATH` environment variable you should never really need to know its path: it can be called from anywhere.

Comment: Thank you Alex. But I need this for my program source code. Because user may have 32bit and 64bit computer location changes. So I thought to get the value from registry by my C++ program. As you said PATH variable might be problematic. Do you think there is a Windows registry entry for wscript.exe path like iexplore.exe? I can use this as default value, if it throws error, I let user to specify location. What do you think?